# Выделяется тег открывающий и закрывающий

Tags: visual-studio-code

Когда выделяю любой открывающий тег.
У меня выделяется сразу 2 тега и открывающий и закрывающий и когда начинаю писать код пишется и там и там. Всё началось после того как я пытался написать сразу в нескольких местах class с помощью Alt + click
вы можете видеть на картинке class= "menu" потом как только всё сделал нажал Esc.
Мне кажется что я начал не то.
Помоги пожалуйста исправить.
Заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При чем здесь javascript? Вы бы хоть редактор указали.

Comment: Visal Studio Code

Comment: Я уже удалял программу и заново устанавливал. Не помогло, думаю проблема в горячих клавишах

Comment: Используйте PhpStorm удобнее и нет проблем. Но если хотите именно эту программу, необходимо удалить со всеми компонентами ( через спец. утилиту). Она сохраняет некие настройки в реестре или где-то еще)

Comment: Хорошо попробую полностью удалить его, если не поможет перейду на PhpStorm. Спасибо!

Comment: Данный функционал появился в одном из недавних обновлений VS Code и не является ошибкой. Очень удобно, если надо заменить один тег на другой или исправить ошибку в уже созданном. Если после названия в открывающем теге поставить пробел, то редактируется только открывающий, и можно дописать любые атрибуты. Поищите в  настройках `mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag` и отключите его.

Answer (score 0):

Данный функционал появился в одном из недавних обновлений VS Code и не является ошибкой.

Очень удобно, если надо заменить один тег на другой или исправить ошибку в уже созданном. Если после названия в открывающем теге поставить пробел, то редактируется только открывающий, и можно дописать любые атрибуты.

Для отключения данного поведения зайдите в настройки:

`File -> Preferences -> Settings`

Далее в поисковой строке введите название настройки: `mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag` (или найдите по названию `mirror cursor on matching tag` в разделе `Extentions -> HTML`) и уберите флаг по умолчанию, чтобы отключить данную настройку.

Comment: Всё сработало!!! Ура!! Спасибо

Comment: @Selfish, если ответ решил вашу проблему, то пожалуйста, отметьте его как верный. Рад был помочь!